# If the series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_1^\infty \frac{{a_n}}{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

The problem:

Show that if $\sum_{1}^\infty a_n$  converges and $a_n ≥ 0$ for all $n ≥ 1$, then $\sum_1^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$
 also converges. Is the statement
true without the hypothesis $a_n ≥ 0$ ?

My attempt:

1) $1\geq\frac{1}{n}$, because $a_n\geq0$ we have $a_n\geq\frac{a_n}{n}$
 =>if $\sum_{1}^\infty a_n$ converge then $\sum_1^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$
also converges.

2) if $\sum_{1}^\infty a_n$ converge then partial sums $s_n$ is a bounded sequence, and $\frac{1}{n}$ is  decreasing and $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow0$ from Dirichlet test we have $\sum_1^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

But I'm not sure if this is correct I feel something is wrong.

Comment: Didn't you already have it at $a_n \geq \frac{a_n}{n}$ by comparison?

Comment: yes but there we know $a_n\geq 0$ at 2) we don'tknow if $a_n\geq 0$

Comment: Ah, I see your question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. I would have used [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) to justify the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}n$ without the assumption that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):a_n\geqslant0$. It allows you to deduce that, say, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{na_n}{n+1}$ also converges.